# bad encoding files names, how do i pick them them up with SSH?

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I have to pick some files from a repertory from each users from a server. The server in encoded in `utf-8` but the files and their names are encoded in `Latin1`. As I have to check for how long they have been in this repertory, the name give me the date they have been putted in.

I'm coding a routine in php to delete them when they have been there for more than 30 days. the syntax for all of them is

`/repertory/account/file_to_delete/dir/dir/dir/.../20160911000943.zip`

I tried to use find for the moment. As I don't want to delete every files I use SSH this way:

```
ssh -l createur ".$iplan."  \"  sudo find ".$filename."  -maxdepth 1  -mindepth 1
```

$filename is a string indicating the way to access the file or folder .
As I don't know all the sub-directory and number of them I create a table if I found a folder (not ending with ".zip") and return table with all folders and directory and do that again.

The routine looks like :

```
function UsingTab($first_tab){
    $data = $;
    while (!empty($data))
    {
        $name_to_check= FolderOrNot(($data[count($data)-1]));
        if($name_to_check== -1){   //-1 mean it is a file, not a directory
            unset($data[count($data)-1]);
        }
        else{
             unset($name_to_check[0]);  
            unset($data[count($data)-1]);   // needed, always having a blank first element in my array
          $data =  array_merge($data,$name_to_check);  
        }
    }
```

My directories can look like "/carte mère (2)/" i can manage the "(" and ")" but not the "è" or any special characters like that. A symbol "?" appears instead...

I tried to make only one array, without -maxdepth but the table is too heavy to use in a browser.
I tried with to connect directly with a console but the "?" are still here. They disappear via FileZilla and the accents are displayed correctly.
I can't change encoding because it is a production server.

Comment: it's not clear where your php is interacting with the file system

Comment: Please fix your caps key - your post is difficult to read. If you want people to help you, don't  make it even more difficult to parse what you've written!

Comment: i'll next time, sorry for that... But i did it on my own, just need to use "LANG=C" in my ssh request. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered that SSH doesn't use automatically the default language and you need to precise it.

```
ssh -l createur ".$iplan."  \"  sudo LANG=C find ".$filename."  -maxdepth 1  -mindepth 1
```

LANG=C is an option which forces the application to use the default language for its output. I hope this will save some one else 6 hours.